# How to validate a column of a table with combination of another columns of another table?

Tags: sql, sas

I have to check for the validation of a field present in one table with the fields present in another table.
I have a table with a Check_Field present in the (Main table) and this Check_Field has to be validated as a combination of two other fields present in another table(Table 2).

**Main Table**

```
Check_Field 
-------------

Field_1%Field_2%
```

**Table 2**

```
Field_1      Field_2
----------------------

 ABC           XYZ
```

In the (Main table) I have to check for the field(Check_Field) which contains value of Field_1 from Table 2 followed by a set of predefined characters which is again followed by value of Field_2 from Table 2 and another set of predefined characters.

Comment: Can you clarify the "predefined character" part? From the "Field_1%Field_2%" I thought you meant that between Field1 and Field2 you could have any string ("%" is the wildcard for LIKE in SQL), but now I'm not so sure about it.

Comment: I have various situations to deal with. In one variant for the % I have to use digits and in another scenario i have to use 2 characters.

Comment: Tried to change my previous answer with these additional info.  If it doesn't work for you,  please add a comment to it; so it will be clearer for us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE M
   WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
              FROM  TABLE2 C
             WHERE M.CHECK_FIELD LIKE C.FIELD1¦¦'%'¦¦C.FIELD2¦¦'%'
        )
```

If you have to verify the string with specific additional characters, you can remove the LIKE and insert your characters in the query.

If for example you need to check for patterns like "(field1)XX(field2)ZZ" the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE M
       WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                  FROM  TABLE2 C
                 WHERE M.CHECK_FIELD = C.FIELD1¦¦'XX'¦¦C.FIELD2¦¦'ZZ'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Type:

```
select * 
    from main_table 
  where check_field in (
     select field_1 from table2
 )
```

This would return value if present in table 2.